# Can the OP of the post be able to accept edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Pretty much the title;

Is it possible for the OP of the question/answer to accept suggested edits?

If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

The OP of any post can approve and/or decline suggested edits instantly.

The OP of a question will *not* be able to instantly accept/decline a suggested edit on an answer given to their question *(that is, if the answer was given by a different user)*.

Comment: In addition to this, the OP of a post cannot review an edit if they are under a review suspension